# How do I add syntax coloring for my custom file type to Visual Studio (not Code)?

Tags: c#, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-2022, dsl, vsix

I have a custom (text-based) file type used by our applications. It's neither XML nor JSON nor YAML, but a custom format (a domain-specific language, if you want to call it that) that meets our needs. We write those files with Visual Studio and our application parses them with a custom parser.

Now, it would be *nice* to have syntax highlighting in Visual Studio when editing those files, so I'm thinking about writing a Visual Studio Extension for that purpose.

Is there an *easy* way to do that (with C# code or a list of regular expressions or some standard grammar format)? So far, I have found:

- Lots of [resources for Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70614576/87698), which won't help, since we use Visual Studio 2022, not Visual Studio Code.
- Instructions on [how to create a custom editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/extensibility/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-editor?view=vs-2015), which seems overkill for our needs. In particular, it seems to require C++ instead of C#. We don't need a custom editor, we just need to extend the default text editor with custom syntax highlighting rules.

Is there an easy extension point to add custom file-format syntax highlighting to Visual Studio (non-Code) that I've missed?

Comment: Just for the record: You already found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/adding-visual-studio-editor-support-for-other-languages?view=vs-2022, I guess. Especially this paragraph: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/adding-visual-studio-editor-support-for-other-languages?view=vs-2022#add-support-for-non-supported-languages which suggests **you can add custom TextMate Grammars** ... unfortunately, the Article has an ambiguous date stamp  "03/10/2023" - but worst case it's from march of this year.

Comment: ^^ I searched with `-"Code" -"Visual Studio Code"` in the term. That improved the results _a little_.

Comment: @Fildor: No, I didn't find that yet. At a first glance, that looks exactly like what I need. Thanks, I'll look into that!

Comment: @Fildor: Yeah, Microsoft seems to like giving different products ambiguous or overlapping names (VS/VS Code, .NET/.NET Framework, Outlook/the new Outlook, etc.). Not ideal for searching.

Comment: I didn't post as answer, because I am just relaying the link and I don't have the capacity to try it out, right now. But if you succeed, I'd like to read about your solution and journey.

Comment: @Fildor: Sure, I'll report back once I've tried it (might take a while, though).

Comment: @Fildor: It worked! I wrote a detailed answer with my experiences. Feel free to move your comment to an answer, so that I can upvote and accept it. (I'll leave my answer as a reference for those interested in the details.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Fildor helpfully pointed out in the comments (and make sure to upvote his answer, if he moves his comment to an answer), Visual Studio syntax highlighting can be extended easily by **putting TextMate grammar files** into a special directory.

---

References:

1. [Microsoft Learn: Add Visual Studio editor support for other languages/Add support for non-supported languages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/adding-visual-studio-editor-support-for-other-languages?view=vs-2022#add-support-for-non-supported-languages)
2. [TextMate grammars](https://macromates.com/manual/en/language_grammars)

---

I tried it and it works quite well, except for one quirk that you need to be aware of: The grammar format described in the TextMate documentation is *not* the format expected by Visual Studio. For example, reference 2 includes the following example file:

```
{  scopeName = 'source.untitled';
   ...
   patterns = (
      {  name = 'keyword.control.untitled';
         match = '\b(if|while|for|return)\b';
      }, ...
}
```

But, for some strange reason (which is probably strikingly obvious for people familiar with TextMate, but which eludes me) Visual Studio needs this information meta-encoded in an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>scopeName</key>
    <string>source.untitled</string>
    ...
    <key>patterns</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>keyword.control.untitled</string>
        <key>match</key>
        <string>\b(if|while|for|return)\b</string>
      </dict>
      ...
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

---

To make a long story short, here is what you need to do:

1. Read and understand [reference 2](https://macromates.com/manual/en/language_grammars). You can skip the parts that require you to follow links (e.g. scopes, foldings).
2. Open `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TextMate\Starterkit\Extensions` (replace `Professional` with your edition of Visual Studio). Note that the folders correspond to programming languages (e.g. `bat` for DOS Batch Files).
3. Choose one of the languages that you want to use as a template and get its `.tmLanguage` file from the `syntaxes` subfolder (e.g. `bat\syntaxes\Batch File.tmLanguage`).
4. Copy and rename that file to `%userprofile%\.vs\Extensions\MyFileFormat\Syntaxes\MyFileFormat.tmLanguage`. Replace `MyFileFormat` with whatever you want to call your file format.
5. Use the knowledge you gained by reading reference 2 to modify the file: The first things you'll want to do are to modify the `fileTypes` value to the file extension used by your custom file format and to set `scopeName` to something unique.
6. Then open a file with that extension in Visual Studio. It should now be color-coded like a DOS Batch file (or whatever you used as your template).
7. Continue modifying your tmLanguage file until you are satisfied with the result. It's not necessary to restart VS every time, but you need to close and re-open your custom file to see the changes in action.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people